# Can we user Simple 2.6.4 (XML serialization ) in Blackberry

Tags: xml, blackberry

I am trying to use simple 2.6.4 in blackberry. But it does not recognize simple's jar. How to do this?

Anyone has tried it before in blackberry?

In normal java project it is working fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "simple 2.6.4 in blackberry" ?

Comment: Simple is xml framework to serialize an object.   more info u'll get on this link   http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a source file picked at random ([VisitorStrategy](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/report/cobertura/org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.VisitorStrategy.html)), it looks like Simple is a Java-SE project that makes use of generics. BlackBerry devices run Java-ME, which is effectively Java 1.3, so cannot use any modern Java library you find.